# C++ Register class member var's at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-mpl, boost-fusion, boost-preprocessor

I try to  implement a Java-Like annotation system using boost MPL and fusion.

Why is it needed:
I need to annotate member var's to have some special runtime features.
I register try them at compile time to my base clase like this:

```
class foo
{
    INIT()

    $REGISTER("test1")
    int test1 = 5;

    $REGISTER("b")
    char* b = "rndmText";

    ....
}
```

My target is a combination of a pointer and a text like $REGISTER(&a,"a") but that's the future target...

The Base class handle all the necessary stuff.
The register macro create a fusion vector:

```
#define INIT() \    
typedef boost::fusion::vector0<> BOOST_PP_CAT(registered, BOOST_PP_SUB(__COUNTER__,2)); \
boost::fusion::vector0<> BOOST_PP_CAT(list,BOOST_PP_SUB(__COUNTER__,2));

#define EXPORT(arg) \
typedef boost::fusion::result_of::push_back< BOOST_PP_CAT(registered, BOOST_PP_SUB(__COUNTER__,4)), const char*>::type BOOST_PP_CAT(registered, __COUNTER__); \
BOOST_PP_CAT(registered, BOOST_PP_DEC(__COUNTER__)) BOOST_PP_CAT(list, BOOST_PP_SUB(__COUNTER__,1)) = boost::fusion::make_list(BOOST_PP_CAT(list,BOOST_PP_SUB(__COUNTER__,7)), arg);
```

This expands (in my case) to:

```
    typedef boost::fusion::vector0<> registered18;
    boost::fusion::vector0<> list19;;

    typedef boost::fusion::result_of::push_back< registered18, const char*>::type registered23;
    registered23 list24 = boost::fusion::make_list(list19, "test1");;
    int test1 = 5;

    typedef boost::fusion::result_of::push_back< registered23, const char*>::type registered28;
    registered28 list29 = boost::fusion::make_list(list24, "b");;
    char* b = "rndmText";;
```

And here is the Problem:
boost::fusion::make_list(..., "test1") create a compiler error and i don't know how to fix it. This is the error:

```
 boost::fusion::joint_view<Sequence,const boost::fusion::single_view<const char *>>::joint_view(const boost::fusion::joint_view<Sequence,const boost::fusion::single_view<const char *>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'boost::fusion::list<T,const char (&)[6],boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_,boost::fusion::void_>' to 'const boost::fusion::joint_view<Sequence,const boost::fusion::single_view<const char *>> &'
```

Can someone help me or have a better idea?

Dominik

Answer (score 3):

This is not really help with the compilation error (sorry) but it was too long for a comment.

> Can someone help / or have a better idea?

I think you are abusing macros. Consider this client code instead:

```
class foo: public registered<foo> {

    int test1 = 5;
    char* b = "rndmText";

public:
    foo();
    virtual ~foo() = default;
};

foo::foo() : registered<foo>{ "foo" } {
    register(&i, "i"); // part of the interface of the base class
    register(&b, "b");
}
```

Explanation:

The same functionality is now provided by a base class. The [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) implementation means that if you have two (or more) classes inheriting from `registered`, they are not in the same class hierarchy (because the adition of metadata should not impose a class relationship between unrelated concrete classes).

The implementation of `registered<T>` could use `boost::fusion` internally (or something else if you need it) and could hide the three meters long declarations behind a handy alias (e.g. `using data_sequence = boost::fusion::vector0<>`).

The `INIT()` part will go naturally in the construction of `registered<T>` instance (and public interface).

This implementation avoids macros completely and allows you to expose metadata to client code in a more elegant way, maybe by simply importing from the API of `registered<T>`.

Comment: This is very close to my first (not posted) solution. With the use of macros i hope to move the register function close to the class member declaration for better readability.

Comment: @Matyro: sounds like a noble goal, but I don't think the macros you wrote help with readability...

Comment: The background source is for most people less important, the front should look fine :p

Comment: @Matyro, you shoot yourself in the foot with that thinking. Consider two aspects:  first, you will spend a lot of time in the lifetime of a project behind the scenes of various interfaces (that's code that _you_ will work on - how do you want it to be? easy to change, or "doesn't matter"?); second, if you write minimal documentation on the API, your clients will rely on that - not on the header files. You should optimize the header files for ease of maintenance as well (macros hurt more than help here).